# Which web site in the Stack Exchange family is appropriate for software related questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, specific-question

I have questions about issues I'm having with Firefox. Which web site in the Stack Exchange network is most appropriate for software related questions?

Clarification: yes, this is a usage question, not programming related.

Comment: Superuser.com. -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SuperUser, I believe.

From the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq):

> Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about …
>
> - computer hardware
> - computer software
>
> and it is not about
>
> - videogames or consoles
> - websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
> - electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they > - interface with your computer
>
> then you're in the right place to ask your question!

Answer (score 2):

If it's about Firefox programming (like XUL or Greasemonkey plugins), try Stack Overflow.

If it's about Firefox usage in a "super user" manner that could be useful to other super users, go to Super User.

As [Jeff says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13224/asking-about-specific-software-on-superuser/13292#13292):

> I think "power user" is the right
>   frame of mind here -- is it an
>   interesting question for other "super
>   users"?